# NDepend for Java

Tags: windows, java, software-development, gui, dependencies

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is a feature-rich GUI for visualizing and analyzing dependencies of .NET applications. Its query language makes it possible to solve very complex tasks, e.g. I managed to identify all COM components that we used in a legacy code project.

I am aware of [JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html), a totally different product, although the naming is similar. Its usability is not so good and AFAIK, it lacks the feature of defining own metrics.

[DeGraph](https://schauder.github.io/degraph/) seems to visualize package dependencies but not e.g. class or method dependencies.

A Java version of NDepend

- must work in Windows
- can cost up to 500 € per developer
- must come with a "language" to define own queries, e.g. "give me all classes that have no methods" or "give me all classes that are not referenced by unit tests" or "give me all classes that use JNI"
- includes graphical visualization of the results
- has trend monitoring, also for own metrics

It would be nice if such a tool integrates in Eclipse, but a standalone tool is also fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this : http://www.jarchitect.com/

I think it is related in some way (not sure)to the company which makes NDepend. It should have what you need, as it also has the code query linq

Comment: Jeez! Why the hell do they promote between CppDepend, VBDepend and JArchitect but not for NDepend? At least it looks almost identical.

Comment: https://www.ndepend.com/ does reference those products in its footer, but no reference back.